# Can Fine-Uploader Parse PDF Pages into Thumbnail Images

Tags: javascript, pdf, fine-uploader

I am working on a website that has a need for a file uploader that integrates well with forms and potentially S3. Fine-uploader looks like a great fit for us. We will be, however, adding a PDF splitter/merger so users can drop one or more PDF files and pull specific pages out and send them as one document. I may need to find a separate JS library to render the PDF pages as image/thumbnails for interaction, but wondering/hoping fine-uploader could handle the page thumbnail rendering similarly to how it does so for image file, but giving a thumbnail for each PDF page.

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader does not natively preview PDFs. If you'd like to generate previews for PDFs client-side, consider using a library specifically for that purpose. One possible choice is [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). You can use Fine Uploader's API to get a handle on the PDF file (`uploader.getFile(id)`) and then pass this file off to pdf.js. Note that you may have to convert this file into a typed array first using `FileReader`.